# Windows 10 UWP Screen Recording API

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, screen-recording

I'm looking for a UWP class like [ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.screencapture).

I want to create a Screen Recorder, but I can't find any class that suits in my needs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application runs sandboxed. It won't have direct access to any API or resource that will let it act outside of its sandbox for reasons of security and system stability. If you are only trying to capture the pixels that your own application is rendering you can use RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync();. If you are trying to capture the pixels from other applications you won't be able to do this from within your own application. If you are running on a desktop computer you have the option of using Win32 APIs to complete your task. For capturing pixels rendered by other applications on devices that don't run the desktop operating system you will be unable to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no api in UWP that would allow you to do that

in order to do that, your app would need to access the screen from background, and that would violate the whole app sandboxing idea

Answer (score 0):

[Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) seems to match closely with the description.